# How to get x and y coordinates of touch in a 3d scene?

Tags: swift, touch, scenekit

I have a plane, and a camera pointed at that plane. If i touch the plane, i would like to get the x and y coordinates of the touch.

[image]

I made a quick image to demonstrate what i want. Basically first the finger touches one place on the plane/screen, and the system prints it's x and y coordinates. Then it touches somewhere else and now it shows the coordinates of the other touch.

Comment: I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tap / Select Node in SceneKit (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006040/tap-select-node-in-scenekit-swift)